# How to make a user input from url

Tags: php, web

So I'm trying to make something like this: `www.someurl.com/toFiles?info=something` and i don't know what to search or what tutorials to look for. I'm asking for a Youtube tutorial or something else that could help me.

Comment: It's simple: (you can replace the info with any url parameter) echo $_GET["info"];

Comment: Asking for recommendations for tutorials etc is off-topic here - see the [help/on-topic] and [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear. But what I understood I am adding here.

Try this:

```
<form method="get" action="https://www.someurl.com/toFiles">
<input type="text" name="info">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

After clicking submit button it will show result like:
[www.someurl.com/toFiles?info=something](http://www.someurl.com/toFiles?info=something)